# Cocos2d-x linux release build (deploy) doesn't include libraries

Tags: linux, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm quite new to cocos2d-x, so this question may be a bit on the amateur side.

I built a release version of my game using  `cocos deploy -p linux -m release`, found it in the bin folder of my cocos project. I compress it into a tarball, send it to my friend so he can try it in a clean Ubuntu VM. Here's what happened:
[image]

Is there a way to include shared libraries in the finished cocos executable or do I have to provide a bash script to install these libraries?